# Es necesario crear procedimientos almacenados en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Buen día,

En este momento estoy desarrollado una aplicación web en donde utilizo procedimientos almacenados o transacciones SQL directamente en el backend de la página.

Me gustaría saber y que alguien me explique en que casos, si es necesario o no utilizar un procedimiento almacenado.

Gracias por la atención prestada.

Comment: Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y podría ser cerrada. La comunidad te ayuda con problemas de programación del código que nos muestres. Deberías revisar a cómo preguntar.